Volumetric Shadows Disappear Near Camera in Eevee Render
I have a cube with a Principled Volume shader and some noise to create volumetric clouds in Eevee. I’m happy with the look, but the problem arises when I render—the shadows seem to disappear as they get closer to the camera.
The left image is from the viewport (everything looks good), and the right image shows the rendered result.
Does anyone have any ideas about what might be causing this and how to fix it?


I found a solution to the issue. The problem was resolved by increasing the Overscan value located under Render > Film > Overscan. After adjusting this setting, everything works perfectly.

